# Grid Modeler grid size

Tags: modeling, add-on

Does anyone know how to increase the size of the grids for a mac with the Grid Modeler addon. I don't know if it was build for a Windows computer and the default button it list is the control button, and maybe it's a different button for the mac, but it's not changing the size of the grid. When I press "a" it changes the mode and the grid size goes from 10 to 5, and I'm still not able to change the grid size still. I found on their site where they say Ctrl or Alt + 7 or 8 may work, but that doesn't do anything either. I think it's because I am using the trackpad to scroll, so I used my wireless Mac mouse, and it still isn't working.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's a third-party addon by the sound of it so you need to ask the author. Having said that, I believe the Mac equivalent of the  Windows control key is the command key so you could try that..

Answer (score 1):

I emailed the maker, and he explained that I can not use the trackpad or the Apple mouse. It had to be a mouse with the wheel on it. also, that some macs either don't come with number keys or the number keys don't work, so he designed it to also use the brackets instead of the number 7 or 8. So you would press "Ctrl + [" or "Alt + [". (without the quotes) The same goes for the other bracket. I hope that helps anyone else.